# Azure Logic App SFTP - SSH Connection failure

Tags: azure, ssh, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I try to list all files of a folder on a SFTP server using Logic Apps SFTP-SSH connector.

When I use WinSCP to connect to this server, my credentials works fine, but when I test my Logic App I got a BadGateway error, with the message : "Permission denied (password)."

[image]

Comment: Could you please check if the ip of logic app can access to your SFTP server ? You can find the ip of the logic app in your region on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#firewall-configuration-ip-addresses-and-service-tags).

Comment: It does not appear to be part of it

Comment: You can't find your region in all of the list on that page ?

Comment: No I misunderstood your first question, sorry. I don't know if the ip of logic app can access the sftp server because it's not mine, I don't manage it